# Can't create a process with CreateProcessW

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, pid, handle

I need to create a process and get a handle and PID of it.

Here is my code:

```
STARTUPINFOW SI;
PROCESS_INFORMATION PI;

SI.cb = sizeof(SI);

std::wstring Name = L"Dummy";

    if (!::CreateProcessW(Name.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &SI, &PI))
    {
        std::wcout << L"Failed to create a process";
    }

HANDLE hDummy = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, PI.dwProcessId);
```

It outputs `"Failed to create a process"` in output Window. I can't see a process in Process Explorer and all values of PI are still 0.

It also gives me this message: `Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA5202C286 (ntdll.dll) in PEX.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.`

Comment: After a successful call to `CreateProcessW`, the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure holds a handle to the process object. If you need a PID instead, pass it into [`GetProcessId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getprocessid). If this doesn't work for you, you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: `PROCESS_INFORMATION` receives both a handle and PID.

Comment: "After CreateProcessW(), value of all PI's members is 0" That's because you're passing "Dummy" as the process command and thus the API is failing.

Comment: CreateProcessW does not return a PID. It returns a BOOL indicating whether or not the call succeeded. You **must not** ignore that.

Comment: Have your tried using `GetProcessId`? As Community said that it can retrieves the process identifier from `PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure. You should try it.

Comment: @Luke, Didn't understood your comment about passing "Dummy". It is the first argument, which means it is an application name.

Comment: So your problem is *not* that you can't get a process handle, because there is no process to get a handle for. Your problem is that you can't start the process, for the reason given in the error variable.

Comment: @user207421, something like that. Sorry, if the title misleading, I discovered later that the issue is in failure of process creation, getting a handle was an initial problem

Comment: @cppu The process you try to create must actually exist as an executable file.

Comment: @Luke, thank you, I looked up an example from book, made an array of WCHAR and passed it in a second parameter, it opens process

Comment: @cppu Simply changing `std::wstring` to `WCHAR[]` won't solve the problem. It is perfectly OK to use a `std::wstring` with `CreateProcessW()`, the problem is something else. On a separate note, when `CreateProcessW()` fails, check `GetLastError()` to find out why. And, make sure to zero out `SI` before passing it to `CreateProcessW()`, otherwise it will contain random junk which `CreateProcessW()` will misinterpret, which is likely the cause of the Access Violation

Comment: @Luke for all we know, the OP does have a `Dummy.exe` on his machine from other exercises.  Don't just assume that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by making an array of `WCHAR`, and passing it to the second parameter of `CreateProcessW`, instead of the first one

Answer (score 1):

(Edit: Note: This is an answer to the original question, not to the edited one...)

```
PI.hProcess
```

This is a **handle** of the process - this is the value that would be returned by `OpenProcess()` (but the access flags differ from `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`).

```
PI.dwProcessId
```

This is the **ID** of the process - this is the value that you can pass to `OpenProcess()`.

(... and the value you seem to be looking for.)

```
PID = CreateProcess(...)
```

This returns a **boolean** value: Unequal to `FALSE` if the process has been created, `FALSE` if creating the process failed.

If this value is `FALSE`, `PI.dwProcessId` and `PI.hProcess` contain **invalid** values.

Note that the Windows API uses the (typedef-) type `BOOL` to store the boolean value (instead of the type `bool`) and it uses the upper-case constants `TRUE` and `FALSE`. Also note that the type `BOOL` can hold more than just two values and that any value unequal to `FALSE` means "true". So comparing using `== TRUE` is not a good idea.

Comment: The ABI type for a `BOOL` is an `INT`, a 32-bit **signed** integer value. Not a `DWORD` (an unsigned integer value). Sounds like nitpicking until `VARIANT_BOOL` enters the scene.

Comment: It is still incorrect. `CreateProcessW` [returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw#return-value) a *"nonzero"* value on success. That value may or may not be equal to the `TRUE` constant. As written, this is an invitation to compare against `TRUE` for equality. Which is the wrong thing to do for practically any boolean type. If you need to compare for equality, compare against `FALSE`, `false`, `VARIANT_FALSE`, ...